# How to show unversioned files checked in commit window

Tags: phpstorm

When I commit changes a windows is opened where I can select which files to commit. By default, tracked files are checked and untracked are not. How to configure PhpStorm so that untracked files will be checked by default?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to check untracked files in the commit dialog by default. 
If you would like to commit newly created files then you need to either **Right-click on file | Git | Add** or **Preferences | Version control | Confirmation | When files are created | Add silently** (in order to add all new files to git by default)